# How to get WYSIWYG of raster layer in print composer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, export, print-composer, printing

I currently have a base raster layer from OSM Standard used in my project. In the regular editing platform for QGIS, the place identifiers for cities are easily readable.

[image]

However, once I enter layout mode to prepare the map, the names become small and unreadable. I think this has something to do with the resampling but I'm not certain how to adjust it.

[image]

How can I modify the raster layer in layout mode so the place identifiers can be read, like in the editing mode?

I'm reposting this because the previous question I was directed to had no definitive answer. The recommendation to change the dpi to 96 severely limits the height/width attributes of the exported map as an image. Also, [changing part of the plug-in code for OSM](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices/issues/43) did not work. In addition the recommendation to download **another** program and to modify an XML file in the new program's repository is overly convoluted.

Comment: just asking the same question again and again will always end in it being marked a duplicate. There is no good solution to this using prerendered OSM tiles. Look to using your own base map if you want that sort of control.

Comment: As mentioned, when it comes to pre-rendered tiles you pretty much have to take what you're served. Suggest you have a look at the free OS Opendata raster maps on offer, GB Overview; 1:250,000 Scale Colour Raster; or MiniScale. https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html. If these don't meet your needs you could have a look at OS Open Zoomstack, which looks to be not bad for small-scale mapping. It's on trial at present, you'll want the GeoPackge: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/blog/2018/07/join-os-open-zoomstack-trial/